# pyenv failed to download a existing version of Python

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I recently installed pyenv and attempted to install a version of python, according to a [blog post](https://hackernoon.com/reaching-python-development-nirvana-bb5692adf30c).  I ran some commands, but encountered an error and I am uncertain how to resolve.

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.6
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/Python-3.6.6.tar.xz
error: failed to download Python-3.6.6.tar.xz

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.6 using python-build 20180424)
```

Comment: I too ma facing the same issue. The terminal does not say anythign else

Comment: I did not find out why this is happening. But I managed to work around the problem by downloading the file manually (I did it with wget) and placing it into ~/.pyenv/cache/ . Then run the install command again.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same error. After digging the pyenv source code, I found the root cause.

Inside `/usr/local/bin/python-build`, it would detect a http client to download the tar file. First choice is `aria2c`, then `curl`, then `wget`.

So check if `aria2c`, `curl` and `wget` can run successfully.

```sh
detect_http_client() {
  local client
  for client in aria2c curl wget; do
    if type "$client" &>/dev/null; then
      echo "$client"
      return
    fi
  done
  echo "error: please install \`aria2c\`, \`curl\`, or \`wget\` and try again" >&2
  return 1
}
```

For my problem, there is something wrong with my `aria2c` command. I upgraded my openssl library before, then all related commands got error when execute them.

```
> aria2c                                                                                                                                              55.5s
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libssh2/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
```

After reinstall `aria2c` and related libraries, problem solved.

Steps to reinstall `aria2c`:

```
> brew uninstall aria2
> brew install aria2
```

Comment: In my case, `brew upgrade aria2 #not aria2c` worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @BigRich Yes, you're right, the brew package name is `aria2`. Steps added in the answer now.

Answer (score 4):

The error can have multiple reasons but you have the ability to use the

```
--verbose
```

flag to get more precise information.

```
pyenv install <your version> --verbose
```

In my case the error was curl installed via homebrew but the path was pointing to the native installation:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
/var/folders/_z/nn_xcbvd3_15l_njz9j9c85c0000gn/T/python-build.20190717020159.52739 ~
Downloading Python-3.5.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.7/Python-3.5.7.tar.xz
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libssh2/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
/Users/johannes/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 368: 53069 
Abort trap: 6           curl -q -o "${2:--}" -sSLf ${CURL_OPTS} "$1"
error: failed to download Python-3.5.7.tar.xz

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.5 using python-build 1.2.13)
```

The fix was to add

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"
```

to my environment.

Answer (score 1):

It solves my problem after reinstalling `aria2` with:

```
brew uninstall aria2' then 'brew install aria2
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case set the environment variable PYTHON_BUILD_HTTP_CLIENT solved the issue.

```html
export PYTHON_BUILD_HTTP_CLIENT=curl
```

Answer (score -1):

appears to have been a network error for me - switched to a faster network after confirming file was still available and it installed without problems